# How to convert Gdiplus::Bitmap* object into HBITMAP

Tags: bitmap, mfc, hbitmap

I am using MFC, now i have a bitmap object, obtained by using:

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* bmp = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(pStream);
```

How to convert this bmp object into HBITMAP? I used :

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
bmp->GetHBITMAP(Color::White, &hBitmap);
```

but it can't, hBitmap always return 0xcccccccc and notices that {unused=??? }. What can i do?

Comment: What is the status return code of the operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer but a way to load a stream into a bitmap. It doesn't need GDI+ at all.

1. Use [CImage::Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tf4bytf8.aspx)
2. Than use the [HBITMAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2czhsdwe.aspx) conversion operator

CImage is a direct slim wrapper for a HBITMAP object from the ATL.

Comment: Thank's xMRi, can you help me about this question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445645/how-to-retreive-thumbnail-on-the-device)

Comment: CImage is a part of ATL/MFC, which isn't available in Express editions of Visual Studio, while GDI+ is available even if you don't use VS at all...